# External javascript cannot run in D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

if I embed javascript code into the html it works fine.

However, if I use 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="draw_chart.js"></script>` just before `</body>`, where 'draw_chart.js' uses d3js to draw SVG. It does not work. I did not see any error message.  What is the problem?

Here are the three files you can download to test:

[index.html](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15562376/index.html)

[draw_chart.js](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15562376/draw_graph.js)

[graph.json](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15562376/graph.json)

**Edit:**

I found the problem, in `draw_graph.js`, I should change

```
var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("svg");
```

to

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("svg");
```

Why cannot I select css style if using external javascript?   (If I embed the .js file into html, it works)

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Is your script being downloaded? Are you sure the script executes before you try to reference it?

Comment: Also, if you can replicate the problem in a small jsfiddle, it's a lot easier to help

Comment: @MikeBell, I have updated to include the files.

Comment: You don't have an element of class "chart" which you are selecting in the Javascript code. Also, you need to include the Javascript *after* defining the relevant HTML.

Comment: @MikeBell I have it, just forgot to attach it, I added it into index.html. Just updated it

Comment: In the future, it'd be better to use a fddle/plunkr to host your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your javscript file is called `draw_graph.js` your index files tries to import `draw_chart.js`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the draw_chart.js file immediately after the  closing tag, but before any other script files that you may have in your HTML file. Also put the d3js file src as the first script file in the  tag.
Good luck